# BLAS.axpy! slower than += in Julia

Tags: julia, blas

Consider the following 4 functions in Julia: They all pick/compute a random column of a matrix `A` and adds a constant times this column to a vector `z`.

The difference between `slow1` and `fast1` is how `z` is updated and likewise for `slow2` and `fast2`.

The difference between the `1` functions and `2` functions is whether the matrix `A` is passed to the functions or computed on the fly.

The odd thing is that for the `1` functions, `fast1` is faster (as I would expect when using BLAS instead of `+=`), but for the `2` functions `slow1` is faster.
On this computer I get the following timings (for the second run of each function):

```
@time slow1(A, z, 10000);
0.172560 seconds (110.01 k allocations: 940.102 MB, 12.98% gc time)

@time fast1(A, z, 10000);
0.142748 seconds (50.07 k allocations: 313.577 MB, 4.56% gc time)

@time slow2(complex(float(x)), complex(float(y)), z, 10000);
2.265950 seconds (120.01 k allocations: 1.529 GB, 1.20% gc time)

@time fast2(complex(float(x)), complex(float(y)), z, 10000);
4.351953 seconds (60.01 k allocations: 939.410 MB, 0.43% gc time)
```

Is there an explanation to this behaviour? And a way to make BLAS faster than `+=`?

```
M = 2^10                                                                                                             
x = [-M:M-1;]

N = 2^9 
y = [-N:N-1;]

A = cis( -2*pi*x*y' )
z = rand(2*M) + rand(2*M)*im

function slow1(A::Matrix{Complex{Float64}}, z::Vector{Complex{Float64}}, maxiter::Int)
    S = [1:size(A,2);]

    for iter = 1:maxiter
        idx = rand(S)
        col = A[:,idx]
        a = rand()
        z += a*col
    end 
end

function fast1(A::Matrix{Complex{Float64}}, z::Vector{Complex{Float64}}, maxiter::Int)
    S = [1:size(A,2);]

    for iter = 1:maxiter
        idx = rand(S)
        col = A[:,idx]
        a = rand()
        BLAS.axpy!(a, col, z)
    end 
end

function slow2(x::Vector{Complex{Float64}}, y::Vector{Complex{Float64}}, z::Vector{Complex{Float64}}, maxiter::Int)
    S = [1:length(y);]

    for iter = 1:maxiter
        idx = rand(S)
        col = cis( -2*pi*x*y[idx] )
        a = rand()
        z += a*col
    end
end

function fast2(x::Vector{Complex{Float64}}, y::Vector{Complex{Float64}}, z::Vector{Complex{Float64}}, maxiter::Int)
    S = [1:length(y);]

    for iter = 1:maxiter
        idx = rand(S)
        col = cis( -2*pi*x*y[idx] )
        a = rand()
        BLAS.axpy!(a, col, z)
    end
end
```

**Update**:
Profiling `slow2`:

```
2260 task.jl; anonymous; line: 92
 2260 REPL.jl; eval_user_input; line: 63
  2260 profile.jl; anonymous; line: 16
   2175 /tmp/axpy.jl; slow2; line: 37
    10   arraymath.jl; .*; line: 118
    33   arraymath.jl; .*; line: 120
    5    arraymath.jl; .*; line: 125
    46   arraymath.jl; .*; line: 127
    3    complex.jl; cis; line: 286
    3    complex.jl; cis; line: 287
    2066 operators.jl; cis; line: 374
     72   complex.jl; cis; line: 286
     1914 complex.jl; cis; line: 287
   1    /tmp/axpy.jl; slow2; line: 38
   84   /tmp/axpy.jl; slow2; line: 39
    5  arraymath.jl; +; line: 96
    39 arraymath.jl; +; line: 98
    6  arraymath.jl; .*; line: 118
    34 arraymath.jl; .*; line: 120
```

Profiling `fast2`:

```
4288 task.jl; anonymous; line: 92
 4288 REPL.jl; eval_user_input; line: 63
  4288 profile.jl; anonymous; line: 16
   1    /tmp/axpy.jl; fast2; line: 47
    1 random.jl; rand; line: 214
   3537 /tmp/axpy.jl; fast2; line: 48
    26   arraymath.jl; .*; line: 118
    44   arraymath.jl; .*; line: 120
    1    arraymath.jl; .*; line: 122
    4    arraymath.jl; .*; line: 125
    53   arraymath.jl; .*; line: 127
    7    complex.jl; cis; line: 286
    3399 operators.jl; cis; line: 374
     116  complex.jl; cis; line: 286
     3108 complex.jl; cis; line: 287
   2    /tmp/axpy.jl; fast2; line: 49
   748  /tmp/axpy.jl; fast2; line: 50
    748 linalg/blas.jl; axpy!; line: 231
```

Oddly, the computing time of `col` differs even though the functions are identical up to this point. 
But `+=` is still relatively faster than `axpy!`.

Comment: Not sure what is going on, but I don't see the same behaviour on my computer. Have you tried profiling?

Comment: Thanks for trying the code! Weird that you don't see a similar behaviour. 
I've updated the post with profiling results.

Comment: Very strange! Running the code on a different computer after updating to Julia v0.4-rc1 and now the `fast?` functions are both faster than their `slow` equivalent...

Answer (score 0):

Some more info now that julia 0.6 is out. To multiply a vector by a scalar in place, there are at least four options. Following Tim's suggstions, I used `BenchmarkTool`'s `@btime` macro. It turns out that loop fusion, the most julian way to write it, is on par with calling BLAS. That's something the julia developers can be proud of!

```
using BenchmarkTools
function bmark(N)
           a = zeros(N);
           @btime $a *= -1.;
           @btime $a .*= -1.;
           @btime LinAlg.BLAS.scal!($N, -1.0, $a, 1);
           @btime scale!($a, -1.);
       end
```

And the results for 10^5 numbers.

```
julia> bmark(10^5);
  78.195 μs (2 allocations: 781.33 KiB)
  35.102 μs (0 allocations: 0 bytes)
  34.659 μs (0 allocations: 0 bytes)
  34.664 μs (0 allocations: 0 bytes)
```

The profiling backtrace shows that `scale!` just calls `blas` in the background, so they should give the same best time.

Comment: Don't benchmark in global scope. Wrap the code in a function or use BenchmarkTools instead. You probably want to interpolate non-const global variables, e.g., `@btime $a .*= -1;`. See also https://docs.julialang.org/en/stable/manual/performance-tips/. Then, `.*=` is the fastest (at least on my PC).